# Redirect an Old Domain to a New Domain (both with HTTPS) in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Let's say we have,

Old Domain : https://olddomain.com
New Domain : https://newdomain.org

Here's my .htaccess file data :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.old.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://new.org/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

this is working good and redirects from old to new domain(i used this in past for changing oter sites domain) but when I try change of address in webmaster tools of google , it says https://old is not redirected to new
what is the solution?

Comment: Please keep a bit of consistency throughout your question. You _talk_ about `olddomain.com`, your code checks for `^old.com`, and then in the webmaster tools suddenly it’s just `https://old`. We can not possibly know whether you were simply careless while posting your question, or whether you actually _used_ different domain names and your problem results from that. So clear that up first of all, please.

Comment: Well, if it is working then it is working. If google reports otherwise then most likely because it does not perform a life check but only visits your site now and then...